# Does the ARIMA function in R differentiate the xreg variable?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima

I am playing around with some time series variables for a sales dataset and have a question about how the Arima function in R handles the Xreg variables.

Say for instance that I forecast a variable x1 12 months into the future with an ARIMA(1,1,0) model and use variable x2 as the explanatory variable. After analyzing ACF and PACF plots and experimenting on x1 I found the (1,1,0) to be appropriate. Then the ARIMA function would look like this:

```
model <- Arima(x1, xreg = x2, order = (1,1,0), lambda = "auto", biasadj = T)
```

and then I'd use forecast(x1, h = 12, xreg = x2_est)

But I wonder, does it only take the first difference of x1, or does it take the first difference of x2 as well? If not automatically, how can I make it do so in order to still maintain equal lenght of x1 and x2 in the Arima function?

Also, what does it do with lambda? Because I get a weird lambda value compared to when calculating lambda individually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. All variables are differenced. See https://otexts.com/fpp2/regarima.html
2. The `lambda` argument is a Box-Cox transformation parameter applied to `x1`. The automated selection is not particularly reliable. Try not specifying `lambda` and see if the residuals are homoskedastic. If they aren't, experiment with different values of `lambda` to see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Find the residuals of X1 and x2 since it is a stationary series. Y depends on X1 and x2 =1+1=2. Lambda is the coefficient of x2:y=X1+lamdax2. Assuming the series to be a white noise series, that is; (neu,epsilon):(mean,zero), Y=(neu+x3+x4+x10+Xt-1) where cov(Xj,Xt+j)=x3+x10+Xt-1 if Xj=1. The residual autocorrelation is part of the ARMA process. The explanatory variable;x2 which is differencing is neu-1=0 which is part of the AR(2) and the Xj is part of the MA(1) processes. The MA(1) contributes partly or is automatically equal to the X1.

Comment: from the autocorrelation and lag estimation, we should assume that j=k parameters, j=0 and k=0. Assuming series to be white noise, the variance will be considered in which x2 will be introduced as the explanatory variable and lambda is the coefficient of x2. The lambda is the value of y2 which is used in estimating the autocorrelation.